# Issue throwing two separate FileNotFoundExceptions Java

Tags: java

I need two separate exceptions, one thrown if the .pro file is missing, the other if the missing file is a .cmd, that current set up has both exceptions being thrown if either one is missing. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.xml.ws.Holder;

public class Inventory {

    static String FileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = args[0];
        String name = args[1];
        ArrayList<Holder> because = new ArrayList<Holder>();

        try {
            File product = new File(path + name + ".pro");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(product);
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(scan.next());
            }
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Inventory <path> <filename>");
            System.out.println("The products file \"" + name + ".pro\" does not exist.");
        }

        try {
            File command = new File(path + name + ".cmd");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(command);

            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(scan.next());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Inventory <path> <filename>");
            System.out.println("The commands file \"" + name + ".cmd\" does not exist.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because both are missing (or the path you use is invalid in both cases)?

Comment: it appears that if either or both are missing, it trips them both, adding a return; to the first makes the test of just the missing .pro file work, but the .cmd one still triggers both exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Try to refactor like this:

```
        File product = new File(path + name + ".pro");
        if (!product.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Inventory <path> <filename>");
            System.out.println("The products file \"" + name + ".pro\" does not exist.");
            return;
        }

        File command = new File(path + name + ".cmd");
        if (!command.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Inventory <path> <filename>");
            System.out.println("The commands file \"" + name + ".cmd\" does not exist.");
            return;
        }
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(product);
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(scan.next());
            }
            scan.close();

            scan = new Scanner(command);
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(scan.next());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me if I change the File objects to the following:

```
File product = new File(path, name + ".pro");
```